# How create a new thumbnailer in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, thumbnails

For a reason I don't know my ubuntu doesn't show thumbnails for pdf.
So, how can I create a thumbnailer in gnome?
More specific - how to create a folder in gconf - /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers?

**UPD**
*in gconf ->-> thumbnailers:*
application@pdf/command = "evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o"
application@pdf/enable = "True"

from console `evince-thumbnailer file.pdf out.png` works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reinstalling document viewer, evince and gnome, thumbnailing started working.
In 11.04 it doesn't work with NFS because apparmor doesn't let evince to go to network.
It can be excluded from apparmor.
In future release that bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With the default pdf reader in Ubuntu any pdf that is in a ebook/manual format and has a cover page is rendered with a thumbnail , the rest is not . If you see practically you don't even need a thumbnail for a pdf if it has no image etc to identify it quickly from the image . Also I believe, when you render files with thumbnails it slows down your machine .